# Disable Mouse Click Operation into Browser's addressbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, address-bar

Being Security Reason now in **Modern Browser** Doesn't Support **location=no** to hide the address bar. So I am Concerning here, to **disable all Mouse Operation** into **address bar**. So that following operation could not be performed into **address bar**.

- No Right Click
- No Left Click
- No Select

Is it possible to do in javascript? Would you please share your an idea?

Comment: Why would you think browsers would let websites do that to you?

Comment: Why do you want to stop the user clicking the address bar?

Comment: just for stopping copy paste the url...

Comment: Why would a user copy-pasting a URL be a problem?

Comment: Use a `position: absolute` iframe if you really want to hide the url.

Comment: @michaelb958: No it is not problem, I just want to know whether it is possible or not to do in javascript...

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to do in JavaScript NO. JavaScript can't change the way the browser works. B

If you are very much interested in achieving this then i can suggest you two ways.

1. Why not use inline pop ups?
2. You can create your own browser, create an adobe air browser by using flex html viewer then you can control the address bar.

But, I don't know your actual requirement so the second point may not be aligned to your requirement.